# Why does my hand-written plugin installer fail to find `request_filesystem_credentials`?

Tags: plugins, core

I'm trying to write a plugin installer, akin to TGMPA, but just for its core functionality of actually installing the plugin and nothing more.

I've identified that `Plugin_Upgrader` is what I need and decided to emulate this.

```
$plugin = THEME_DIR . '/Inc/Plugins/my-shortcodes.zip';
$options = array(
        'package' => $plugin,
        'destination' => WP_PLUGIN_DIR,
        'clear_destination' => false,
        'clear_working' => true,
        'is_multi' => true,
        'hook_extra' => array(
            'plugin' => $plugin,
        ),
);

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php';

class My_Upgrader extends Plugin_Upgrader
{
    public function run( $options )
    {
        $result = parent::run( $options );
        return $result;
    }
}

$upgrader = new My_Upgrader;
$upgrader->run($options);
$upgrader->install( $plugin );
```

Unfortunately, this throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function request_filesystem_credentials()     
in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-upgrader-skin.php:93     
Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\class-wp- 
upgrader.php(187): WP_Upgrader_Skin->request_filesystem_credentials(false, 
'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', false) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp- 
admin\includes\class-wp-upgrader.php(693): WP_Upgrader->fs_connect(Array) #2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\amaranth\header.php(53): 
WP_Upgrader->run(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp- 
content\themes\amaranth\header.php(59): My_Upgrader->run(Array) #4 
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template.php(688): 
require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp- 
includes\template.php(647): load_template('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', true) #6 
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\general-template.php(41): 
locate_template(Array, true) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp- 
content\themes\amaranth\index.php(15): get_header() #8 C:\xampp\htdoc in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-upgrader-skin.php on 
line 93
```

It has something to do with its...skin? Am I missing something?

A few notes:

- I understand that the Filesystem module would default to FTP if it
  can't write to `wp-content`, as such, this error might pop up, but
  it's not the case. WP can write to `wp-content`.

***Disclaimer: This is a very dumb installer, but I gotta start somewhere. Any suggestions are welcome.***

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that `request_filesystem_credentials()` is undefined. So make sure that function is defined by including the file before `class-wp-upgrader.php`.

```
include_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
```

Comment: totally not `admin_url` as you need a path not a url

Comment: Aha! Close, I figured it out, kinda ashamed this didn't occur to me. See my answer.

Comment: @MarkKaplun oops

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to include the files necessary for these functions to work.

And so, here's your dirty-quick way to install plugins:

```
$plugin = THEME_DIR . '/Inc/Plugins/my-shortcodes.zip';
$options = array(
        'package' => $plugin,
        'destination' => WP_PLUGIN_DIR,
        'clear_destination' => false,
        'clear_working' => true,
        'is_multi' => true,
        'hook_extra' => array(
            'plugin' => $plugin,
        ),
);

require_once ABSPATH  . 'wp-admin/includes/misc.php';

if(!function_exists('request_filesystem_credentials')){
    require_once ABSPATH  . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
}

if( !class_exists('\Plugin_Upgrader')) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php';
}

class My_Upgrader extends Plugin_Upgrader
{
    public function run( $options )
    {
        $result = parent::run( $options );
        return $result;
    }
}

$upgrader = new My_Upgrader;
$upgrader->run($options);
$upgrader->install( $plugin );
```